# Python version specifier union

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools

I'm trying to specify an `install_requires` directive for `setuptools` that indicates my package requires `Django>=1.4.14,<1.5` **OR** `Django>=1.5.9,<1.6` **OR** `Django>=1.6.6,<1.7` **OR** `Django~=1.7`.

From reading [PEP 400 Version Specifiers section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers) this doesn't seem possible.

Am I missing something or the only way to correctly achieve similar result is to explicitly exclude all unwanted minor version releases?

```python
"Django>=1.4.14,%s,%s,<1.8" % (
    ','.join("!=1.5.%d" % v for v in range(9)),
    ','.join("!=1.6.%d" % v for v in range(6)),
)
```

Comment: That's rather a convoluted requirements section. Why so specific? If you support 1.4 through 1.7, just stick to `>= 1.4, < 1.8`. If specific Django versions in that range have problems, that's a documentation issue.

Comment: `1.4.14`, `1.5.9` and `1.6.6` included a security fix required for my package that are part of `1.7.*`. Plus my package won't be required on `>=1.8` since the feature has been merged upstream.

Comment: Then bail out at runtime if the feature is missing, and document this.

Comment: I think it's up to the users to ensure they have applied security fixes, not to the package developer?

Comment: @michel-slm you might be right, it's just that the security issue fixed by those releases is even more easy to abuse with my package.

Comment: Ah, then do the version check when the package is imported and fail hard